# How to prevent caret from changing size on inline html element in content editable div

Tags: html, css

When using the contenteditable attribute on a div and have inserted a html element span in, for some reason the caret changes position when next to the span.

So you can see the caret has been pushed up:

[image: image of content editable problem]

What is it that controls the caret position and what mechanisms do I have to alter it?

**html:**

```
<div style="resize:none; overflow: auto; border: none" contenteditable="true">
            is your email still <span class="inline-button" contenteditable="false">Email</span>?
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.inline-button {
    background-color: green;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-weight: bold;

    font-size:0.8em;
}
```

```css
.inline-button {
 background-color: green;
 border: none;
 color: black;
 padding: 4px 4px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px;
 pointer-events: none;
 font-weight: bold;

 font-size:0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div style="resize:none; overflow: auto; border: none" contenteditable="true">
   is your email still <span class="inline-button" contenteditable="false">Email</span>?
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the padding on the `span`.

```css
.inline-button {
 background-color: green;
 border: none;
 color: black;
 padding: 0px 4px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px;
 pointer-events: none;
 font-weight: bold;

 font-size:0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div style="resize:none; overflow: auto; border: none" contenteditable="true">
   is your email still <span class="inline-button" contenteditable="false">Email</span>?
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the issue, if you get rid of the question mark you can see the caret still visibly gets smaller.

Comment: @Hidden That is because of the different font-size inside the span.

Comment: Why does the caret go inside of the span? Is there a way round that?

Comment: @Hidden no idea. Throw a comment if you figure it out ;).